# RichTextToolbar in GWT 2.3

Tags: gwt, richtextbox

I'm trying to create a RichTextArea (following the GWT Showcase : [link](http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwRichText) )

When I do a code completion of RichTextToolbar, I'm not able to find it. Is this an external library?

And then I googled and found this : [google code link](http://code.google.com/p/richtexttoolbar/downloads/detail?name=RichTextToolbar.css&can=2&q=). Is this the same library in the Google Showcase? Or is the RichTextToolbar is an old implementation that not being brought to version 2.3?

Update:I tested this and what I feel is although the implementation the same, the UI looks different though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that they created their [own version of RichTextToolbar](http://www.google.com/codesearch#A1edwVHBClQ/samples/showcase/src/com/google/gwt/sample/showcase/client/content/text/RichTextToolbar.java).

This class is part of the [GWT Showcase](http://www.google.com/codesearch#A1edwVHBClQ/samples/showcase/src/com/google/gwt/sample/showcase/).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a decent explanation to get the RichTextToolbar working. You take the source code from showcase basicaly.

http://www.jeanhsu.com/2010/06/10/how-to-use-richtexttoolbar-in-gwt/